# @EnableJdbcHttpSession in Standard Spring Config (no Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

I have a spring application and Multi-Node Server with Sticky Sessions. I want to keep the session in the database so as not to make replication sessions.

I tried to implement the `jdbc` session store using `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` but I did not manage to create a configuration so that the sessions in the database would work.

I have `spring-session-jdbc` in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

also have :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class AppConfig{

    @Autowired
    private AppEnvironment env;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getDatabaseUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getDatabaseUserName());
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getDatabasePassword());
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(env.getDatabaseValidationQuery());
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(env.isTomcatTestOnBorrow());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.valueOf(env.isJpaShowSql()));
        jpaAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.humanbizz.web.entities" });
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getHibernateDialect());
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_catalog", env.getDefaultCatalog());
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getHbm2ddlAuto());

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", String.valueOf(env.isIdNewGeneratorMappings()));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", env.getDefaultSchema());
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", String.valueOf(env.isConnectionUseUnicode()));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet", env.getConnectionCharSet());
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource); 
    }

}
```

My HttpSessionApplicationInitializer:

```
public class HttpSessionApplicationInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer{

    public HttpSessionApplicationInitializer() {
        super(AppConfig.class); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(WebSecurity.class, Datasource.class);

      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(WebMvc.class);

      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =  container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");

      container.addFilter("securityFilter",  new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
      .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    }

}
```

I have a generated scheme at the database like here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-sqlserver.sql

but when you start the application, the session is not stored in the table, I do not know if I missed anything in the configuration, everything I found that should be set up this one but it does not work, any ideas and help would welcome me

Comment: I tried now with this dependency but no change. when I delete the necessary tables in the database I generated with this scheme, I issue an error about the non-existence of the table, and when the table exists there is nothing written in it

Comment: I did not, I created tables manually. I've added this parameter now, but it does not change things

Comment: I tried now, but I do not work, I do not know where the entry of the session is based on what I see in `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` `@Scheduled` has only to delete a session that has expired

Comment: The problem is the fact that you override the `onStartup` method which destroys the automatic registration of the filter for Spring Session to do its work. I strongly suggest to use multiple dedicated initializers instead of cramming everything into 1.

Comment: if I do not override the `onStartup` in the web application, the initialization of the application will not start

Comment: Because you aren't using multiple initializers... You should have 1 for bootstrapping your servlet and context loader, one for security and one for the session stuff. The fact is you are breaking the default behavior yourself and are amazed that it stopped working. You should at least be calling `super.onStartup` in your code to make it work.

Comment: Something different is that your tx setup is flawed, you are using the wrong tx-manager for JPA, you should be using the `JpaTransactionManager` instead of the `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you have override the `onStartup` method of the `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` with that you break the whole purpose of the `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` which is to register the filter needed for Spring Session to do its work.

I would suggest using multiple `WebApplicationInitializer` so that you can take advantage of the defaults instead of reinventing the wheel. In your case that would mean 3 `WebApplicationInitializer`.

1. Bootstrap your application and servlet
2. Configure security
3. Configure Spring Session

To configure your application I suggest extending the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` which basically does all you now do manually.

```
@Order(1)
public MainApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class, WebSecurity.class};
    }

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvc.class };
    }        
}
```

Now that you have loaded all of your configuration you need to enable Spring Security for that create a class that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`.

```
@Order(2)
public SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {}
```

This class is all you need as it will detect the configuration from the root context which is already loaded before hand.

Finally you want the Spring Session stuff and for that create a class extending `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer`.

```
@Order(3)
public SpringSessionInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {}
```

Again all you need as it will detect the filter in the earlier created configuration. You might want to place an `@Order` on each to make sure they get executed in the right order.